# filtering and searching not working in magento 2 custom grid in product edit page

Tags: ajax, grid, admin, product, magento2

i have created one custom grid as new tab in product edit page.data is displaying in grid form.searching or sorting is not working there.if i put

```
 $this->setUseAjax(false);
```

then every time total product page is reloading.if i put ajax as true giving ajax error.so what we have to define in grid if we writing that as custom tab in product admin

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution? Please post here.

Comment: Hi, try https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/154710/14039.